# Build 0.5 T solenoid with

Tags: electromagnetism, solenoid

I want to build 0.5T solenoid (Length 30 cm and diameter 0.5 cm). Can anyone provide me the formula taken into account the length, radius of the solenoid and Radius of wire, i.e. Outer radius after wind the wire. I know this formula (B=uNI/L).

Answer (score 4):

For a long thin solenoid the radius doesn't affect the strength much. All that matters is the turn *density* (how closely the turns are packed together) and the current.

Magnetic field strength is proportional to current multiplied by turn density. To get 0.5T inside a bare coil (μ=0.0000012566) you need about 400000 Ampere Turns per meter. For a 0.3m solenoid that could be 120000 turns at 1A, or 12000 turns at 10A, or 1200 turns at 100A.

The wire can be any thickness that fits without making the solenoid too fat. For a single layer of 1200 turns the wire radius must be 0.3m / 1200 / 2 = 0.125mm or smaller. A double layer coil could use wire that is twice as fat (because you only need half as many turns per layer) but would increase coil diameter by 0.5mm.

Minimum acceptable wire thickness is determined by how much current the wire can take without melting. Thinner wire has higher resistance and so dissipates more power and gets hotter. The wire inside a multi-layer coil heats up more because it is surrounded by other (hot) wire.

0.125mm radius = 0.25mm diameter or 30AWG. That size copper wire has a resistance of about 0.35Ω/m. Circumference = Pi*D, so the total length for 1200 turns of single layer coil with 5mm inside radius is 5.125mm*2*Pi = ~39m, which has a resistance of ~13.5Ω. 100A passing through this coil would create about 13.5Ω*100A<sup>2</sup> = 135kW of heat. It might last a few microseconds before burning out.

A double layer coil could use 0.5mm diameter or 24AWG, which has a resistance of ~0.088Ω/m. This coil would measure 3.4Ω and dissipate 34kW. To drive it you would need 340VDC at 100A. It might last a few more microseconds.

Comment: 45T hybrid DC magnet is made of flat conductors made from copper segments alternating with insulators with a spiral overlap area.  Look from 4:08 onwards in the following YouTube video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGytW_C6hR8